# Change ZIP to POSTCODE in Estimate Shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

I'm working with the madison island template in 1.9.1 and when you are viewing the cart the shipping estimator shows COUNTRY, STATE/PROVINCE, ZIP.
I'd like to change STATE/PROVINCE to read as CITY/REGION and also ZIP to read as POSTCODE.
Can somebody describe which files and where in those files I need to amend to achieve that please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

**1.** Directly in the translation file -

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv.
```

**2.** If you activate inline translate in the admin panel -`> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Frontend : Yes (don't forget to add your IP in Developer Client Restrictions -> Allowed IPs).`

---

These are the proper ways of doing it. But it will change these words everywhere on the checkout. So if you like to change them only in the Estimator - there is another way (but it's not recommended) - to change them in the template file - `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`.

Comment: ok, so for example if I use the first option where I change the Mage_Checkout.csv, should I change "State/Province","State/Province" to "State/Province","City/Region"? I only need to do the first option you gave right?

Comment: Yes, you have to do only 1 of the 3 options. And yes, you have to change `"State/Province","State/Province"` to `"State/Province","City/Region"`. Please accept my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: I amended the translation file but the update did not show on the page I mentioned, so I changed the wording in the shipping.phtml and it looks fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, when you need to do this exclusively in "Estimate Shipping" Block in cart page, Go to app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml and edit it simply :)